# Split text of input button into 2 lines, on on-top of the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input button that I'd like to take the text "Estimate Shipping" and make it look like:

"Estimate
 Shipping"

Instead. How can I do that?

Here is my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/946Jw/).

Sample HTML:

```
    <div class="span12">
    <form class="form-vertical form-inline" id="ShipEstimate" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="control-group floating-label-form-group">
    <fieldset>
    <div class="controls">
    <label for="PostalCode_Ship" title="Zip">
    Enter Zipcode:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="PostalCode_Ship" value="45356" name="PostalCode_Ship" onchange="populateCartTotalInCartPage();" minlength="5" placeholder="Enter Zipcode">
    <input type="hidden" id="Country_Ship" name="Country_Ship" value="US">
    <input type="button" onclick="populateCartTotalInCartPage();" value="Estimate Shipping" id="GetQuotes" class="btn btn-orange">


    <input type="radio" style="display:none" id="shipping_method" name="shipping_method" value="1000022" onchange="populateCartTotalInCartPage();"> 



    <input type="radio" style="display:none" id="shipping_method" name="shipping_method" value="1000001" onchange="populateCartTotalInCartPage();"> 



    <input type="radio" style="display:none" id="shipping_method" name="shipping_method" value="1000004" onchange="populateCartTotalInCartPage();"> 



    <input type="radio" style="display:none" id="shipping_method" name="shipping_method" value="1000005" onchange="populateCartTotalInCartPage();"> 



    <input type="radio" style="display:none" id="shipping_method" name="shipping_method" value="1000009" onchange="populateCartTotalInCartPage();"> 



    <input type="radio" style="display:none" id="shipping_method" name="shipping_method" value="1000010" onchange="populateCartTotalInCartPage();"> 


    </div></fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: whats the question here?

Answer (score 4):

In order to break the button input value, you could use [line feed character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm) `&#10;` (HTML entity) as follows"

```
<input type="button"  value="Estimate&#10;Shipping">
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/946Jw/1/)**.

You can also use `<button>` element to move the second word to the next line:

```
<button>
  Hello <br>
  World!
</button>
```

Comment: Or `Estimate&#x00A;Shipping` as Hexadecimal ;-)

Answer (score 3):

word break helps you there

```
#getQuotes
{
    width: 94px;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rSmRs/)</kbd>

```
<button>
Estimate<br />
Shipping 
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to set the width of the button so that the second word wraps to the next line. Alternatively, you can also use the `<button>` tag:

```
<button>
Estimate<br />
Shipping 
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline `style` attribute like below.

```
<input type="button" onclick="populateCartTotalInCartPage();" value="Estimate Shipping" id="GetQuotes" class="btn btn-orange" style="width:90px !important;word-break: break-word;">
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/946Jw/3/)